# Failed to connect to server postgres django

Tags: django, postgresql

I configured postgresql on the server as I was told by technical support, but when I go to the page and try to send mail, an error appears:

```
OperationalError at /decision/livingrooms/kitchen/provans/
не удалось подключиться к серверу: В соединении отказано
    Он действительно работает по адресу "caparolcenterspb.ru" (217.107.219.83)
     и принимает TCP-соединения (порт 5432)?
```

Comment: Maybe the port is blocked by the firewall?

Comment: and how to test it?

Comment: @МарсельАбдуллин `sudo ufw status` usually shows what is blocked and what is not, unless you are running different firewall

Answer (score 0):

If you are running linux `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` `sudo systemctl start postgresql` This will restart all the services, or try to start `postgres` without `daemon-reload` first to see what it returns

Comment: i can't get a sudo privileges through ssh oh hosting system

Comment: @МарсельАбдуллин Can't really help you then, my last guess is to chech if the database engine is set correctly in django `settings`